# jQuery click function and list items

Tags: html, jquery

Lately, I'm having trouble with jQuery click events. In this example, I'm wanting to use ajax post when an user clicks on a list item. No errors pop up on Firebug and the jquery script is in the code. When I run the code, nothing happens. The code is below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$('#pop').click(function() {
var pop = 'pop';
$.post('ajax_file.php', {
    style: pop
    }, function(data) {
        $('#tube').html(data);  
        });});
</script>

<ul>
    <li id="pop">Pop</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `<script>` is just enough. And wrap your code into a *ready* `$(function(){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#pop').click(function() {
       var pop = 'pop';
       $.post('ajax_style_homepage.php', {
         style: pop
       }, function(data) {
           $('#tube').html(data);  
       });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in the document [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function and see what happens. Also you dont need to empty. You can call the `html` method and it will overwrite the content.

```
$(function(){
   $('#pop').click(function() {
        var pop = 'pop';
        $.post('ajax_style_homepage.php', { style: pop}, function(data) {
            $('#tube').html(data);  
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to do the same thing as the 2 other answers without binding your click method at page load.  Simply set your onclick attribute on your list item to a function containing your ajax call.  This is easier to follow in my opinion.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function makeAJAXPost(){
    var pop = 'pop';
    $.post('ajax_file.php', {
        style: pop
        }, function(data) {
            $('#tube').html(data);  
    });     
}
</script>

<ul>
    <li onclick="makeAJAXPost()" id="pop">Pop</li>
</ul>
```